# how to pass kerberos ticket to jboss server (5.1.0 AS) from swing client

Tags: java, swing, single-sign-on, kerberos, spnego

My swing client has got access to the kerberos ticket and needs to pass it to Jboss server  ver 5.1.0 AS to authenticate on server for EJB look up, is there any way to pass this ticket?